# Adding a Custom Field to be used by Posts 2 Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, plugin-gravity-forms, plugin-posts-to-posts

I'm trying using Gravity Forms and allow for a user to submit a post to my CPT, and choose an optional Connected Post Type.

I have two CPTs, CPT1 and CPT2.

When they're viewing my form for creating a post under CPT1, I want them to be able to choose an associated post that's under CPT2.

I've been following Travis Smith's instructions on [creating a custom field](http://wpsmith.net/2011/plugins/how-to-create-a-custom-form-field-in-gravity-forms-with-a-terms-of-service-form-field-example/), which has gone pretty smoothly.

However, I'm trying to follow the [Posts 2 Posts documentation](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Custom-admin-boxes) about adding custom admin boxes.

I'm not sure where to start and how to achieve what I'm looking to accomplish.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you really need to use the custom admin boxes, unless you need to customize labels, etc...

```
<?php
function my_connection_types() {
    // Make sure the Posts 2 Posts plugin is active.
    if ( !function_exists( 'p2p_register_connection_type' ) )
        return;

    p2p_register_connection_type( array(
        'name' => 'cpt1_to_cpt2',
        'from' => 'cpt1',
        'to' => 'cpt2',
            'admin_box' => 'from',
    'fields' => array(
        'field_name' => 'field_title',
        'field_name2' => 'field_title2'
    )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_connection_types' );
?>
```

And if you need to add custom labels, you can just extend the registration array to include:

```
 'from_labels' => array(
      'singular_name' => __( 'Person', 'my-textdomain' ),
      'search_items' => __( 'Search people', 'my-textdomain' ),
      'not_found' => __( 'No people found.', 'my-textdomain' ),
      'create' => __( 'Create Connections', 'my-textdomain' ),
  ),
```

Then, to update a form field in Gravity Forms based on the connection, you can use the gform_pre_render filter to populate your field; something like:

http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Dynamically_Populating_Drop_Down_Fields
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_pre_render

Short on time, but if I get a chance I'll update with a more specific Posts2Posts example.  I'm sure if you dig into his admin box class a bit, you'll be able to combine it with the filter above to get the results your looking for.

Comment: Hey Gil, thanks for the response.  I've seen those docs and been able to use them successfully in a regular theme circumstance, but the issue I'm having is trying to integrate it into Gravity Forms.  I'm trying to create a custom field using the above connectors.  Any thoughts how I can get that AJAX CPT<->CPT connector available as a custom field in Gravity Forms?

Comment: Updated the answer a bit -- the docs referenced should give you a solid idea of how to apply the filter to your Gravity Form, but you'll probably need to dig into the code / docs for Posts2Posts on how to pull an array of all relatable posts.